# Error: Declaration annotated with @OptionalExpectation can only be used in common module sources

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

*Update (2018-11-03)*

This is a known issue that is being tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26589).

*Original Post*

I am playing around with Kotlin MPP, specifically with Kotlin 1.3 and the new structure. After converting a Kotlin 1.2 MPP to the new structure, I keep getting these errors:

```
Error:(3, 18) Kotlin: [MPP_jvmMain] Declaration annotated with '@OptionalExpectation' can only be used in common module sources
```

These are referring to the `@JsName()` annotations I have within my common module.

I have tried:

- Starting a completely new MPP from scratch using the built-in wizard, and simply adding `@JsName("test")` to the `hello()` function that comes with the generated sample. Even that seems to cause problems.
- Invalidating caches/restarting IntelliJ
- Using the latest versions of everything (Kotlin 1.3, IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 Ultimate)
- Calling `./gradlew build` from the command line. This works.

[Sample project here](https://github.com/jguerinet/MPP-JsName-Bug)

[Link Kotlin Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26589)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed within v1.3.10 of the Kotlin plugin for IntelliJ.