# Kotlin - Declaration annotated with '@OptionalExpectation' can only be used in common module sources

Tags: maven, kotlin, compilation, sonarqube

I am getting the subject error trying to compile Kotlin (**1.3.50**) via maven (works with gradle).
 I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216175/error-declaration-annotated-with-optionalexpectation-can-only-be-used-in-commo) but have not found a solution.  My situation is different in that the statements getting this compile error are annotated with `@SharedImmutable` and `@ThreadLocal` (from kotlin.native.concurrent).

- I've compared gradle dependencies with maven dependencies.
- I am intrigued by the [18 Jun 2019 15:48 statement here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26589) about the algorithm to determine common sources.  I have set arg `-Xcommon-sources` in the **kotlin-maven-plugin** configuration to the file that the compiler is generating the errors on.

This is a iOS and android MPP (`-Xmulti-platform` is also an arg for **kotlin-maven-plugin**), but I am trying to get code coverage with JaCoCo, thus the reason for trying to compile (Kotlin for JVM) with maven and eventually using the sonarqube plugin.  I am not compiling any iOS specific code.  Code coverage does not show up in sonarqube when run via gradle ([tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076853/sonarqube-not-picking-up-both-kotlin-and-java-coverage-gradle-project))...so I am taking a shot in the dark here by running JaCoCo/sonar via maven...I am blazing a trail at my company by using Kotlin and gradle for the build.

Ideas?